# Meaning of -1 as length value when creating a VBasic array?

Tags: .net, vba

I've recently read this line of code:

```
Dim someArray(-1) as String
```

and I'm wondering:

- is -1 a valid value for the array length?
- what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using -1 as the length indicator when declaring an array in Visual Basic means that the array will be empty, that is, it will have zero elements. More information here: [Arrays in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) (search the *Zero-Length Arrays* section).

Answer (score 2):

Since the size of an array can't possibly be negative - that is the size indicates how many Strings (in this case) the array can hold which, obviously, can't be a negative value.

By declaring an array with -1 you are creating an array with a length of 0.